# Create Google Calendar Events with Live Stream Generated

Tags: google-calendar-api

resouce: https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events

Add video and phone conferences to events

```
conferenceProperties.allowedConferenceSolutionTypes[] : "eventHangout", "eventNamedHangout", "hangoutsMeet"
```

i have successfully create event with Google Meet link generated. and if i want to add sream to my event. i must manually add/ edit event in Google Calendar Interface. is there any possibility this feature

```
virtual ConferenceParameters Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.ConferenceData.Parameters
```

> Additional properties related to a conference. An example would be a
>   solution-specific setting for enabling video streaming.

i have read https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/namespaceGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar.html

but cant find how to generate meet link and stream at the same time using API. is possible to do this?
if this feature unavailable yet. i have submitted here https://issuetracker.google.com/153114077

*i'm using Gsuite for Edu.*

Comment: It is not possible at the moment the create a streaming link with the API. Thanks for creating the Feature Request. Here is the [link to the FR](https://issuetracker.google.com/153114077) for other that want to add +1 to it.